# My success message displays in conjunction with my error message

Tags: javascript

When a player makes the correct guess, the error alert displays first then the success alert displays. I only want an error alert to display on an error and a success to display upon success.

I tried including the success alert in the if else statements.

Comment: Hey, when asking a question, be sure to keep it as short as possible while including all the information needed to answer your question. You seem to have a lot of information here that doesn't directly contribute to your question. Thanks!

Comment: What doesn't pertain to my question? How can one know what isn't working if I don't post what makes the code break?

Comment: I think the js function and the HTML inputs would have been sufficient. The rest doesn't really shape the outcome of your problem. However, all of it would be acceptable if you wrote a code snippet instead of a code sample, where it would be required to replicate the entire program/page.

Comment: Ok I made edits. Not familiar with SO yet. Thanks.

Comment: No please explain @StackSlave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure alert always runs. There's no if statement to prevent it.

Try this:

```
if(guessBoxes[guess-1] == "X"){
    alert("GAME OVER - YOU FOUND IT! A WINNER");
} else {
    alert("SORRY WRONG GUESS!; ");
}
```

Also, instead of that first if - else statement, just return false if they enter an invalid number. It eliminates the need for the large else statement and increases code readability:

```
function playGuessingGame() {
    var guess = document.getElementById("numberToGuess").value;
    var date = "";
    if (isNaN(guess) || guess < 1 || guess > 9) {
        alert("YOU CAN ONLY PLAY WITH NUMBERS 1-9 ");
        return false;
    }
    var gemPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var guessBoxes = ["O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"];
    guessBoxes[gemPosition - 1] = "X";
    if (guess == 1) {
        document.getElementById("guessBox1").innerHTML = guessBoxes[guess - 1];
    } else if (guess == 2) {
        document.getElementById("guessBox2").innerHTML = guessBoxes[guess - 1];
    } else if (guess == 3) {
        document.getElementById("guessBox3").innerHTML = guessBoxes[guess - 1];
    } else if (guess == 4) {
        document.getElementById("guessBox4").innerHTML = guessBoxes[guess - 1];
    } else if (guess == 5) {
        document.getElementById("guessBox5").innerHTML = guessBoxes[guess - 1];
    } else if (guess == 6) {
        document.getElementById("guessBox6").innerHTML = guessBoxes[guess - 1];
    } else if (guess == 7) {
        document.getElementById("guessBox7").innerHTML = guessBoxes[guess - 1];
    } else if (guess == 8) {
        document.getElementById("guessBox8").innerHTML = guessBoxes[guess - 1];
    } else if (guess == 9) {
        document.getElementById("guessBox9").innerHTML = guessBoxes[guess - 1];
    }
    if (guessBoxes[guess - 1] == "X") {
        alert("GAME OVER - YOU FOUND IT! A WINNER");
    } else {
        alert("SORRY WRONG GUESS!; ");
    }
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML;
}
```

Here is a working codepen with the changes:

https://codepen.io/ZorlacMeister/pen/wVJzKv

I've moved the gemPosition and guessBoxes variables outside of the function, since that function is called every time you click on the button. I also added the gameReset function.

Comment: These changes are still showing the error alert first.

Comment: Please explain how you're testing. I tested it in jsfiddle and it works fine. However, the number to guess is changed every time you click on the button, then the box you guessed is marked with a O. I'm not sure if that's what you wanted or not. If it is, you must move the gemPosition definition outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ridiculous, so I wrote something simple to help you understand:

```js
var doc, bod, I, guessingGame; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body; 
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
guessingGame = function(guessInput, outputDiv, resetButton){
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1;
  guessInput.onchange = function(){
    var s = this.value, n = +s, r;
    if(!s.match(/^([1-9]|10)$/)){
      r = 'Invalid Number';
    }
    else if(g === n){
      r = 'You Win!';
    }
    else{
      r = 'Guess Again';
    }
    outputDiv.innerHTML = r;
  }
  resetButton.onclick = function(){
    g = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1; guessInput.value = outputDiv.innerHTML = '';
  }
}
guessingGame(I('guess'), I('out'), I('reguess'));
}); // end load
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0; border:none; outline:none;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
#content{
  padding:7px;
}
lable{
  display:inline-block;
}
#guess{
  width:40px; font-size:14px; padding-left:3px; margin-left:4px;
}
input[type=button]{
  padding:2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='content'>
    <label for='guess'>Pick a number between 1 and 10</label><input id='guess' type='number' value='' min='0' max='10' maxlength='2' />
    <input id='reguess' type='button' value='reset' />
    <div id='out'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```